# Dynamically load jpg files

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I want to load in an image view different jpg files based on a txt file that I read sequentially. I've put the jpg files in assets.
I've found the following code to use:

```
((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/data/data/com.myapp/files/someimage.jpg"));
```

I tried to insert:

```
(GetApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets()+"file.jpg")
```

Knowing that I use android studio what is the recommendation:

1. How to find my "assets" path
2. Is it the assets dir that I should use
3. Any recommendations on another method

The directory system is not at all easy on android!

Answer (score 0):

If you want load images in assets directory, you can do like this,

`InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(imageFileName);`
`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);`

OR

put images in drawable dir, then use them as resources.

`int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("fileNameWithoutExtension", "drawable", context.getPackageName();`
`Drawable drawable = context.getResource().getDrawable(drawableId);`

Comment: Thanks for your help! but both methods did not work. following through debugger everything looks fine. Except that thr res looks for drawable-hdpi-v4. so I created this dir manually but it doesn't change anything. What should I look for?    the ony modif I changed to your code is initializing context = getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your help! Much appreciated!

code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           drawJPG();
        }
    });

}

private void drawJPG() {
    Context context = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    context = getApplicationContext();
    try {
        is = context.getAssets().open("myjpg.jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}
```

doing debugging it looks fine at bitmap()

```
this = {android.graphics.Bitmap@830031440008}
nativeBitmap = 2052352744
buffer = {byte[201300]@830031238688}
width = 275
height = 183
density = -1
isMutable = false
isPremultiplied = true
ninePatchChunk = null
layoutBounds = null
```

option 2:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           drawJPG();
        }
    });

}

private void drawJPG() {
    Context context = null;
    context = getApplicationContext();
    int drawableID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("myjpg", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableID);

}
```

it looks still ok through debugging:

```
this = {android.content.res.Resources@830030928528}
value = {android.util.TypedValue@830030928808}"TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x3 "res/drawable-hdpi-v4/myjpg.jpg" a=4 r=0x7f020000}"
id = 2130837504
isColorDrawable = false
key = 17179869187
cs = null
dr = null
file = {java.lang.String@830031232520}"res/drawable-hdpi-v4/myjpg.jpg"
```